# Реформы образования: что вы об этом думаете?

Tags: общие-вопросы, образование

Вопрос не по грамматике, но обойти это вниманием я не могу. Вот, что попалось на сайте http://fognews.ru:

> В новом учебном году русский язык
> может стать необязательной
> дисциплиной. Уже с 7 класса ученики
> смогут отказаться от изучения русской
> литературы, а с 9 класса — и русского
> языка. Реформа образовательного
> процесса будет происходить в рамках
> всероссийской программы «Предметный
> выбор», согласно которой, по заявлению
> учащегося, он сможет самостоятельно
> выбирать дисциплины, которые будет
> изучать. За современные методики в
> школьном образовании выступили многие
> педагоги, по мнению которых изучение
> русского языка и литературы в рамках
> школьной программы является пустой
> тратой времени. Учеников заставляют
> писать сочинения, читать многотомные
> произведения русской классики, где
> встречаются слова, незнакомые нашим
> детям, понуждают выполнять сложные
> упражнения. Вот это как раз и не
> нравится ни директорам школ, ни
> значительной части педагогов. В
> поддержку инновационного подхода
> преподавания русского языка выступила
> и Вита Кириченко «Лучший учитель
> Москвы-2012». По ее мнению, школьные
> сочинения себя давно изжили, а
> единственно верным способом проверки
> знаний считает ЕГЭ по русскому языку.

Что вы об этом думаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Речь идет о том, что ученики смогут выбирать, что и в каком объеме им изучать. Надеюсь, что они окажутся мудрее горе-реформаторов. Тем более что об отмене экзаменов никто и не заикался. А экзаменационные задания не становятся легче. Наоборот. Вообще, информация мне кажется не совсем соответствующей действительности. Авторы не совсем понимают то, о чем пишут. Да и о сути "современных методик", "инновационного подхода" - ничего не написано.А что без этого обсуждать-то? Я думаю, что русский язык из обязательной программы не исключат никогда. Ведь русский язык  - это не только предмет изучения, но и средство изучения всех других наук, средство формирования мысли.

Answer (score 0):

> Вот, что попалось на сайте http://fognews.ru:

Этим все сказано. Дальше можно не читать.

> Авторы не совсем понимают то, о чем пишут.

Я бы сказал: совсем не понимают.

> Вита Кириченко «Лучший учитель Москвы-2012». По ее мнению, школьные сочинения себя давно изжили, а единственно верным способом проверки знаний считает ЕГЭ по русскому языку.

Хотелось бы видеть первоисточник. Не могла Вита Викторовна такое ляпнуть.

Comment: Непонятна система ссылок. У автора вопроса и у отвечающего ссылка одна и та же, а темы, вроде бы, разные. О чем речь? Я увидела статью на тему "русские для русских", весьма глупую и популистскую.